# Finding all possible paths between two nodes in a large graph

Tags: python, graph, path, depth-first-search

I'm using the following python code for finding all possible paths between two nodes but it return any thing, just waits for running.

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return []
    if start not in graph:
        return []
    paths = []

    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            print (node)
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

My graph has about 4K nodes and 23K edges.

Comment: I suppose you want to exclude looping paths, otherwise there are an infinity of them...

Comment: basic debugging technique: run your code on a simple example first! If it works then gradually increase the size of your problem. If it just gets too slow, then work on optimizing it.

Comment: is the function actually recursive or is the indentation bad?

Comment: my last comment was wrong. Just btw, last time I had to work on graph I used [SageMath](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) there are really good tools for graph, and you can leave your script running in cloud computing (you code in python)

Comment: Sure I want to exclude loops

Comment: @JulienBernu It works on a very simple graph but the problem is here with a large graph with about 4K nodes.

Comment: @SiavashR Are you sure that the problem isn't a really long execution time ?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It is recursive and DFS and I want to use the function for a large graph

Comment: @pwnsauce It is really very very very long execution time

Comment: @SiavashR wo what happend when you start it ? Do you see the output of `print (node)` ? are you sure your script stop at some point ?

Comment: Have you considered the fact that unless your graph is very special, the number of possible paths is growing exponentially?

Comment: @pwnsauce In a simple graph it stops with the list of all possible paths between two nodes. But in a large graph, it doesn't.

Comment: @exponentially I think I have to set a threshold value to avoid very long paths

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using dynamic programming which I don't know how to use that